# Does every living thing pass into the force after it dies?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In the "Clone Wars" Series 6, episode 12 "Destiny", Yoda has a hallucination where he sees a vision of a dying Ashoka within the Jedi Temple. She asks

> *You cast me out of the Jedi order... tell me,* ***will I still be able to become one with the force when I die?***

This suggests that non-Jedi (or Sith?) cannot join the Force. However, in Episode III, Yoda tells Anakin:

> *Death is a natural part of life. Rejoice for those around you who transform into the Force. Mourn them do not. Miss them do not. Attachment leads to jealously. The shadow of greed, that is.*

And in Episode VI, Yoda says

> *For my ally is the Force, and a powerful ally it is. Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter. You must feel the Force around you; here, between you, me, the tree, the rock, everywhere, yes. Even between the land and the ship.*

So... does every living thing pass into the Force after death? Also, what the heck happens to things after they die/rejoin with the Force?

Comment: @Null sorry, pluralising 'Sith' to 'Siths' is a mistake I keep making in my questions and answers... I should've learned it by now, but no xD

Comment: No need to apologize. I just put the note in my edit so you'd know I changed it to the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read so far, no. Not only not the "living", but most of the Jedi did not "become one with the Force". Let us quote, at this point, moments after the order to execute Order 66, Jedi Masters Bol Chatak, Roan Shryne and Chatak's padawan Olee Starstone talking about their inability to sense other Jedi on Murkhana, the planet on which the three is also running away from clone troopers:

Star Wars: Dark Lord, The Rise of Darth Vader, by James Luceno, page 39

> ...Shryne made adjustments to his comlink. "Still no response from any of them. And not because of signal jamming." Knowing that Chatak was doing the same, he stretched out with the Force, but no reverberations attended his call. Chatak's shoulders slumped.
>
> "They've been killed." Starstone sighed and hung her head.
> "Draw on your training, Padawan," Chatak said quickly. "They're with the Force."
> *They're dead*, Shryne thought.

Becoming one with The Force was a concept not unheard of, but considered to be a technique long lost, until Qui-Gon made contact with Yoda.

So far, the first "recent" Jedi known to have gained the ability to retain consciousness and contact the living after death is Qui-Gon Jinn. How he gained the ability, I haven't read yet, if it's been written that is. Afterwards, Yoda, Kenobi and Anakin Skywalker join the ranks, able to manifest themselves as Force ghosts. The rest is, well, Expanded Universe.

Comment: Yoda learns about it towards the end of the Clone Wars series, in the final season that aired on Netflix instead of TV. Qui-Gon guided him to some priestess' to teach him ways of the Living Force. At the end of Episode III, Yoda hints that he will teach Obi-wan how to contact Qui-Gon while he is in hiding on Tatooine. Anakin learns it from Sidious.  There have been other examples of force ghosts, but as you say, they are all in the Legends EU, which is not canon anymore.

Comment: I remember some EU stuff about Luke appearing to people etc... mind you, EU has practically *everything* in it, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Force is the science equivalent of the general cosmic field that envelopes everything including all living matter. So scientifically speaking it does exist.
Since energy cannot be destroyed, **the answer is yes**, when anything alive dies, it's energy gets back to the general energy pool, therefore becoming one with it.

The suggestion that not everyone becomes one with the Force may

- be a propaganda means of the Jedi
- be a reference to the possibility of manifesting one's self through the Force after death as some Jedi can.